# Datatable row grouping with hide option

Tags: jquery, datatable

In my Datatable, I have most rows with unique value of ID but some rows have the same value. For the rows having same value, I would like to show only one row with that ID and hide all other rows. The one row that is displayed, should have a button to allow other rows of the same id to be visible.

As seen in this example : https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html

I don't want grouping for ids that are unique and for duplicate IDs show only one row, with additional rows shown through a button.

Answer (score 0):

So I have a working example, but it is admittedly lacking robustness and CSS styling.  This example will work if the table always displays all of its rows.  If you plan to use the pagination features, I would ask if you have access to the structure of your data before it reaches your DataTables code.  I also did not test my example against dynamic additions or subtractions to the dataset.  Here is the link to JS Fiddle.  If you have any other specific requirements, I will gladly discuss those, but hopefully this is enough to get you started.

**HTML**

```
<table id="mydt" class="display full-width"></table>
```

**CSS**

```
.full-width {
    width: 100%;
}

.hideMe {
    display: none;
}
```

**JS**

```
function idCol() { return 0; /* the index of the ID column */ }

function countRowsById(rows) {
  function extractId(row) { return row[idCol()]; }
  function sumByGroup(prev, current) {
    if(prev[current]) {
      prev[current] += 1;
    } else {
      prev[current] = 1;
    }
    return prev;
  }
  return rows.map(extractId).reduce(sumByGroup, {});
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var dt = $('#mydt');
  dt.dataTable({
    pageLength: -1,
    data: [
      ["Foo", "Bar", "Baz"],
      ["Fizz", "Buzz", "Bam"],
      ["Foo", "Boo", "Moo"],
      ["This", "Row", "Here"],
      ["That", "Row", "There"],
      ["This", "One", "Too"]
    ],
    columns: [
      { title: "ID" },
      { title: "B" },
      { title: "C" },
      {
        title: "See More",
        data: null,
        orderable: false,
        defaultContent: "",
        class: "see-more"
      }
    ],
    order: [0, 'asc'],
    drawCallback: function(settings) {
      var api = this.api();
      var rows = api.rows().nodes();
      var rowData = api.rows().data();
      var last = null;
      var counts = countRowsById(rowData);
      api.column(idCol()).data().each(function(idVal, index) {
        // append the id to the parent row
        $(rows).eq(index).data('id', idVal);
        if(last !== idVal) {
          if(counts[idVal] > 1) {
            // There are multiple rows
            // This is the first row
            $(rows).eq(index).find('.see-more').html('<a href="#" class="show">Show</a>');
          }
        } else {
          // This is a subsequent matching row
          $(rows).eq(index).addClass('hideMe');
        }
        last = idVal;
      });
    }
  });

  function idFilter(id, i, el) {
    return $(el).data('id') === id;
  }

  function showHideMes(id) {
    dt.find('.hideMe').filter(idFilter.bind(null, id)).each(function(i, el) {
      $(el).removeClass('hideMe').addClass('showMe');
    });
  }

  function hideShowMes(id) {
    dt.find('.showMe').filter(idFilter.bind(null, id)).each(function(i, el) {
      $(el).removeClass('showMe').addClass('hideMe');
    });
  }

  dt.on('click', '.see-more .show', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('show').addClass('hide').html('Hide');
    var rowId = $(this).parents('tr').data('id');
    showHideMes(rowId);
  });

  dt.on('click', '.see-more .hide', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hide').addClass('show').html('Show');
    var rowId = $(this).parents('tr').data('id');
    hideShowMes(rowId);
  });

});
```